collision problem with javascript graphics
I'm attempting to create a platformer on the codehs website using javascript graphics. I did the physics and it all worked fine, but when I got the collision script from an online source, the player snaps into place at the edge of the rectangle and then falls instead of reducing the velocity. Another problem is when the player reaches the edge of a rectangle when it is above ground, instead of falling to the ground, it falls and recovers back to the last position.
setSize(500, 500);

var rect = new Rectangle(100, 50); 
rect.setPosition(getWidth()/2 - rect.getWidth()/2 , 400); 
rect.setColor(Color.yellow);
add(rect);

var rect2 = new Rectangle(100, 50); 
rect2.setPosition(50 , 345); 
rect2.setColor(Color.yellow);
add(rect2);

var width = getWidth();
var height = getHeight();

var player = {
    x: 300,
    y: 200,
    width: 24,
    height: 24,
    speed: 3,
    velX: 0,
    velY: 0,
    jumping: false,
    grounded: false,
},
    keys = [],
    friction = 0.7,
    gravity = 0.4,
    boxes = [],
    powerup = [];
    
    
var drawPlayer = new Rectangle(player['width'], player['height']); 
drawPlayer.setPosition(getWidth() / 2, 300);
drawPlayer.setColor(Color.black);
add(drawPlayer);

var ground = new Rectangle(getWidth(), 70); 
ground.setPosition(0, 450);
add(ground);
//adding obstacles
boxes.push({
    x: rect.getX() ,
    y: rect.getY() ,
    width: rect.getWidth(),
    height: rect.getHeight(),
    color: rect.getColor()
})

boxes.push({
    x: ground.getX(),
    y: ground.getY(),
    width: ground.getWidth(),
    height: ground.getHeight(),
    color: ground.getColor()
})

boxes.push({
    x: rect2.getX(),
    y: rect2.getY(),
    width: rect2.getWidth(),
    height: rect2.getHeight(),
    color: rect2.getColor()
})
    
function start() {
    setTimer(tick, 1); 
}

function tick() {
    playerMovement();
}

function playerMovement() {
    player['grounded'] = false;
    player['y'] += player['velY'];
    player['velY'] += gravity;
    drawPlayer.setPosition(player['x'], player['y']);

    
    //collision
    for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        var dir = colCheck(drawPlayer, boxes[i]);
        if(dir === 'b') {
            player['jumping'] = false;
            player['grounded'] = true;
        } else if (dir === 'l' || dir === 'r') {
            player['velX'] = 0; 
            if(dir != 'r') {
                if(keys[68]) {
                    player['velX'] += 2;
                }
            }
            
            if(dir != 'l') {
                if(keys[65]) {
                    player['velX'] -= 2;
                }
            }
            player['jumping'] = false; 
        } else if (dir === 't') {
            player['velY'] *= -1;
        }
    }
    
    player['velX'] *= friction;
    player['x'] += player['velX'];
    
    if(player['grounded']) {
        player['velY'] = 0; 
    }
    
    //movement 
    if(keys[65]) {
        if(player['velX'] > -player['speed']) {
            player['velX'] -= 2;
        }
    }
    
    if(keys[68]) {
        if(player['velX'] < player['speed']) {
            player['velX']+= 2;
        }
    }
    if(keys[87]) {
        if(!player['jumping'] && player['grounded']) {
            player['jumping'] = true;
            player['grounded'] = false;
            player['velY'] = -player['speed'] * 2.5;
        }
    }
}




//cool algorithmn for checking collision between shapes.
function colCheck(shapeA, shapeB) {
    // get the vectors to check against
    var vX = (shapeA.x + (shapeA.width / 2)) - (shapeB.x + (shapeB.width / 2)),
        vY = (shapeA.y + (shapeA.height / 2)) - (shapeB.y + (shapeB.height / 2)),
        // add the half widths and half heights of the objects
        hWidths = (shapeA.width / 2) + (shapeB.width / 2),
        hHeights = (shapeA.height / 2) + (shapeB.height / 2),
        colDir = null;

    // if the x and y vector are less than the half width or half height, they we must be inside the object, causing a collision
    if (Math.abs(vX) < hWidths && Math.abs(vY) < hHeights) {
        // figures out on which side we are colliding (top, bottom, left, or right)
        var oX = hWidths - Math.abs(vX),
            oY = hHeights - Math.abs(vY);
        if (oX >= oY) {
            if (vY > 0) {
                colDir = "t";
                shapeA.y += oY;
            } else {
                colDir = "b";
                shapeA.y -= oY;
            }
        } else {
            if (vX > 0) {
                colDir = "l";
                shapeA.x += oX;
            } else {
                colDir = "r";
                shapeA.x -= oX;
            }
        }
    }
    return colDir;
}

//keydown, keyup methods.
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
});

I've tried re-arranging the gravity and friction, this is the best I got. I think that the problem is due to the collision detecting, but I don't know any of these formulas for it. If anyone could help maybe re-create a new collision function and explain it, it would be a great help for me in school.

how to execute this code?

codehs.com, i think it’s free?
